# Action inside another action not working

Tags: actions, footer

I am trying to load content before the end body tag on admin pages that have a TinyMCE editor on them. To do this I am trying to leverage two action hooks 'before_wp_tiny_mce' and 'admin_footer' but it does not seem to be working as I expected. The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
add_action( 'before_wp_tiny_mce', 'before_wp_tiny_mce_action' );

function before_wp_tiny_mce_action() {
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'admin_footer_action' );
}

function admin_footer_action() {
    echo "<p>I am in the footer of an admin page with a TinyMCE editor.</p>";
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: By all means it should. Do a `echo 'xxx'; die;` in each to make sure they are getting called properly. May have a typo in the something?

Comment: Fully tested. No typos... Both hooks work on their own but not when referenced inside the other one.

Comment: Would you mind posting your actual code? _The devil is in the details_...

Answer (score 1):

I think I worked out the problem.

`before_wp_tiny_mce_action` is not an action hook called before the actual TinyMCE editor in the DOM. It is called before the script that is loaded via the `admin_print_footer_scripts` action. So I think the `admin_footer` action hook is before the `before_wp_tiny_mce_action` action hook so I am calling my action too late.

I am going to have to find another way of detecting if a page has TinyMCE on it before it starts writing the script.